# Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged with ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I want to pull data from a database to display into a ComboBox, and then allow users to select values from that ComboBox and add them into a ListBox (via add/remove buttons). Would I be able to get away with using an `ObservableCollections` to hold the database values to bind to the ComboBox, since it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` (and `CollectionChanged`)? Sorry if this is a basic question, I starting learning WPF about a month ago.

I've read over the [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23772/WPF-A-Beginner-s-Guide-Part-5-of-n) (very well done) by Sacha Barber.

And I've looked over the MSDN page on [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx).

What would be the advantages/disadvantages of using an `ObservableCollection` vs a `List` (which I know does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items in your combobox don't change (i.e. you don't add/remove/update items), then `List` will probably be OK for your needs (`ObservableCollection` will be too) if you manually notify that your `List` property changed when you affect it.

```
public List<X> MyList
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }

    set
    {
        if (... != value)
        {
            ... = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyList"));
            }
        }
    }
}

....

this.MyList = new List<X> { new X(...), new X(...) };
```

If you plan to add/remove or update items in your combobox (without creating a new `MyList` object, i.e. using `this.MyList.Add(...)`), then use `ObservableCollection` that is able to notify when the collection is updated (so it can update bindings).

Comment: I did plan on updating the list bound to the combobox, thanks!! One question: In your example, would the list have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?
i.e.  public List<X> MyList : INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: In the example, the list itself doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It's the class that contains a property of type `List` that does.

Answer (score 2):

Something you may want to note.

Don't confuse the ObservableCollection's implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged with the objects it contain's implementation.

If one of the properties of one of the objects within the ObservableCollection changes, the UI will not reflect it unless that object implements INotifyPropertyChanged as well.  Do not expect the ObservableCollection to take care of this for you.

Comment: Ok, so if I had a custom class with several properties stored in an observablecollection, the observablecollection would not know if one of those properties changed unless that custom class implemented INotifyPropertyChanged? But if the observable collection just held strings that never changed then this would not be an issue, correct? Thanks.