# Easiest way to implement a WPF Listbox with an Observable Collection

Tags: wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I see tons of questions on this topic and the answers are, in my limited C# and WPF experience, overly complex.  I cannot believe that Microsoft has made it this difficult (to me ) to implement a collection bound to a Listbox that changes during runtime.

Here's the deal: I have a Listbox that contains items (list of emails, actually).  What occurs is that I need the Listbox to refresh when a new email arrives or gets removed from the source Folder.  Sounds easy enough, but manipulating the Observable Collection in anyway is causing the dreaded "This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread."

So nevermind for a moment about circumventing this problem by writing dispatcher stuff.  Is there some "normal" way to manipulate a collection that's NOT from another thread? -- this is what I'm confused on.  Where else would I modify the collection?  I'd happily place my code there if this is what's expected.

My current implementation -- which may very well be poor -- is to place the Folder.Items event handlers within the collection class itself that will then add/remove emails from the collection (i.e. itself).  This ain't working and I don't really understand how else one would accomplish this.

---

Okay, I whipped up this code example. This is NOT my application but it pretty much represents how I'm (incorrectly) handling things...and this will throw the 'cannot update source collection thread error'.  The example is broken into 3 sections, first is the XAML markup, then Main class and method and the ObservableCollection class.

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" >
        <Border BorderBrush="#FF404020" BorderThickness="5" Margin="0" Background="#FFFFFFC0" CornerRadius="25">
            <ListBox x:Name="lbList" Margin="50" FontSize="21.333" DisplayMemberPath="Subject"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MailList ml = new MailList();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olApp = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application;

            Folder f = (Folder)olApp.Session.PickFolder();  // User picks MAPI Folder
            f.Items.ItemAdd += new ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(this.UpdateListBox);     //Folder.Item add event, calls  UpdateListBox
            foreach (object o in f.Items)
            {
                if (o is MailItem)
                {
                    ml.Add((MailItem)o);    //Add Mailitems to ml collection
                }
            }

            Binding b = new Binding();      //create binding for ListBox
            b.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
            lbList.DataContext = ml;
            lbList.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
        }

        public void UpdateListBox(object o)     //Add new MailItem to ml collection
        {
            if (o is MailItem)
            {
                ml.Add((MailItem)o);
            }
        }

    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public class MailList : ObservableCollection<MailItem>
    {
        public MailList()
            : base()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790455/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-with-observablecollection

Comment: You need to post some code cause you are making the way harder than it needs to be.   It is as easy as binding to a pubic OC property and then add an item to the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is supposed to be the problem with dispatching collection changes to the UI-thread? As far as i know that is the usual way to go.